How to mimic request like a Search Engine Bot?
I want to fetch the site content like a Search Engine bot. I want to get the content of some restricted pages because I have seen that GoogleBot is allowed to see them.
How can I do so?
What I have tried so far is the following Python script:
import requests
    
# Define the URL you want to crawl
url = 'https://mayeenulislam.github.io/bot-detector/'

# Set the headers to mimic a search engine crawler
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'
}

# Send the GET request
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Successfully fetched the page!")
    print(response.text)  # Print the content of the page
else:
    print(f"Failed to fetch the page. Status code: {response.status_code}")

But I had no luck.

Where did you get that user agent string? Maybe try the one listed here:  Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) Chrome/W.X.Y.Z Safari/537.36

Note that sites have other ways of deciding wether a request is actually coming from a Google crawler: see here. tl;dr: you can check if the requestor IP is in a Google-published list of crawler IPs. If this is the case you will have a tough time getting a response.

I'm afraid this particular Agent string is giving me: Failed to fetch the page. Status code: 403. Regarding the other deciding factor, it might not always work, yes you are right.
